# Went down for restart, won't come back up

Tags: boot

I installed updates, GNOME3, xampp, netbeans and a set of drivers. I went to restart the machine, and when coming back on, it hangs on a purple screen trying to turn back on. When I try to tap escape in order to get into the "safe" mode, it still hangs on the purple screen then eventually displays `^[^[^[^[` on the screen. It doesn't respond to keystrokes after that, but it does respond to the power button - it shuts back down gracefully, with the Ubuntu logo.

I booted into the cd and just ran it from there, so I'm thinking I can try and fix whatever damage is done and try to boot back from the hard drive. Any ideas on what went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: "and a set of drivers"... I'm guessing this is the problem if you've already purged gnome3 with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Third**
Gnome-3 installed from ppa is know to cause bugs for some people. Let's revert to Gnome-2 and after we have a functional Graphical environment then you may re-install Gnome-3, what do you think?

Run these commands at terminal successively one by one:

```
sudo apt-get remove libgtk-3-common
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel  
sudo reboot now
```

If you still have problems then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Reference: [here](http://www.ajopaul.com/2011/04/26/ubuntu-11-04-uninstall-gnome3-and-revert-to-gnome-2-x/).

**Second**
Try to re-set the default Desktop Manager. At terminal, run this:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`

**First**
After the boot you can go to a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) then try to reconfigure xorg pasting this:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

Comment: I did get into terminal and ran that command, then I restarted and I'm back to a blank screen.

Comment: No dice there either, unfortunately =/

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick. I think I'll just stick with ubuntu desktop for now

Comment: That's a wise decision ;-)